# Unable to launch Chrome in remote webdriver

Tags: automated-testing, selenium-webdriver, selenium2, c#

I have tried the following three options . I am using C#

```c#
DesiredCapabilities capabilities = DesiredCapabilities.Chrome();
capabilities.SetCapability("chrome.binary", "pathtogooglechrome\chromedriver.exe");
_remoteWebDriver = new ScreenShotRemoteWebDriver(new Uri("http://127.0.0.1:4444/wd/hub"),
                    capabilities);
```

or

```c#
ChromeOptions options = new ChromeOptions();
options.BinaryLocation = "pathtogooglechrome\chromedriver.exe";
capabilities.SetCapability(ChromeOptions.Capability, options);
_remoteWebDriver = new ScreenShotRemoteWebDriver(new Uri("http://127.0.0.1:4444/wd/hub"),
                    capabilities);
```

or

```c#
System.Environment.SetEnvironmentVariable("webdriver.chrome.driver", "pathtogooglechrome\chromedriver.exe");
_remoteWebDriver = new RemoteWebDriver(new Uri("http://127.0.0.1:4444/wd/hub"),
                  DesiredCapabilities.Chrome());
```

After the `SetEnviromentVariable` if I try the following code I get path of the `ChromeDriver.exe`

```c#
string temp = System.Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("webdriver.chrome.driver");
```

I always get the same error `System.InvalidOperationException : The path to the driver executable must be set by the webdriver.chrome.driver system property`
I want to know what I'm doing wrong here, why path is not accepted?

If any alternative solution is available please let me know.

Answer (score 3):

From [documentation](http://selenium.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/docs/api/dotnet/html/AllMembers_T_OpenQA_Selenium_Chrome_ChromeOptions.htm):

```
BinaryLocation  
Gets or sets the location of the Chrome browser's binary executable file.
```

So the above excerpt plainly says that the `BinaryLocation` is the path for `chrome.exe` and not `chromedriver.exe`.

And `chromedriver.exe` path should be defined in the `PATH` environment variable.

So in your case the correct line would be:

```
options.BinaryLocation = @"pathtogooglechrome\chrome.exe"
```

Notice the `@` in `C#` that will let you put un-escaped characters. Otherwise you would have needed `\\` instead of `\` etc.